# Import alias from nearliest parent

Tags: babeljs, tsconfig

How to config babel to import alias like my idea ?

```
./src
    |
    --themes.ts // root theme
    |
    |Module-1
        |
        --themes/index.ts // child module's theme extend root theme
        --component.tsx   // import "@themes" instead of "../themes"
    |
    |Module-2
        |
        --themes/index.ts // child module's theme extend root theme
        --component.tsx   // import "@themes" instead of "../themes"
    |
    |Module-{x} // any modules...
        |
        --themes/index.ts // child module's theme extend root theme
        --component.tsx   // import "@themes" instead of "../themes"
```

At child dirs. module-{x}/.../component.tsx,
Inside component.tsx of any module, instead of import "../themes" -> import "@themes"

My regular babel.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./'],
        alias: {
          '@themes': './src/themes'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

is this a right way approach ?

```
  root: ['./src/{module-x}/'],
  alias: {
    '@themes': './src/{module-x}/themes'
  }
```

import "@themes" access "module-x/themes" of its root module-x